Are we supposed to fight everyone and kill those who disbelieve?
It is narrated in Ibn Ishaq 992:

“fight everyone in the way of allah and kill those who disbelieve in allah“

I know Ibn Ishaq is generally a weak source, however I'd like to know just how weak this is.
Does it reach the level of fabrication for example? Likewise, what is the context of the situation? If this is a general narration applicable for everyone, does it not contradict the fact we are only supposed to kill non-combatants and ask for Jizya beforehand?

The quote is from Seerah Ibn Ishaq, you can read the context here in Arabic and  here in English. It records the instructions given by the Prophet ﷺ to Abdur Rahman ibn Awf when dispatching him to the expedition of Dawmat al-Jandal, they include:

Fight for the sake of Allah
Fight against those who disbelieve
Do not steal from the collected spoils of war
Do not be treacherous (when you have made a treaty)
Do not mutilate the dead or prisoners
Do not kill children

Authenticity
The hadith itself is authentic. It is present in Mustadrak al-Hakim and other collections with a Hasan chain. The part quoted in this question is also present in the Sahih hadith of Muslim which records the instruction given by the Prophet ﷺ when dispatching expeditions:

اغزوا باسم الله في سبيل الله قاتلوا من كفر بالله اغزوا و لا تغلوا ولا تغدروا ولا تمثلوا ولا تقتلوا وليدا
Go out to fight in the Name of Allah, for the sake of Allah. Fight those who disbelieve in Allah  Fight but do not steal from the war booty, do not break your promises, do not mutilate and do not kill children
— Muslim

Everyone
Islam does prescribe fighting all the disbelievers by default. 'All' here means regardless of whether they are e.g. Christian or atheist, Roman or Mongol, militant or pacifist etc.
The hadith conveys this because it says:

قاتلوا من كفر بالله
Fight against those who disbelieve in Allah

This literally applies to everyone who disbelieves, regardless of their category.
The same is conveyed in the Quran:

وقاتلوا المشركين كافة
And fight against the disbelievers collectively
— Quran 9:36 see Tafsir:  و ( كافة ) معناه جميعا


قاتلوا الذين يلونكم من الكفار
fight those adjacent to you of the disbelievers
— Quran 9:123 see footnote 1 for explanation


فاقتلوا المشركين حيث وجدتموهم
kill the polytheists wherever you find them
— Quran 9:5

And the hadith:

أمرت أن أقاتل الناس حتى يشهدوا أن لا إله إلا الله وأن محمدا رسول الله، ويقيموا الصلاة، ويؤتوا الزكاة، فإذا فعلوا ذلك عصموا مني دماءهم وأموالهم إلا بحق الإسلام، وحسابهم على الله
I have been ordered (by Allah) to fight against the people until they testify that none has the right to be worshipped but Allah and that Muhammad is Allah's Messenger (ﷺ), and offer the prayers perfectly and give the obligatory charity, so if they perform that, then they save their lives and property from me except for Islamic laws and then their reckoning (accounts) will be done by Allah.
— Bukhari

Jizyah
Jizyah means tribute. As a specialized term it used to mean tribute that is given by non-Muslims while living under Islamic rule. When Muslims plan to invade an enemy they give them three options:

Accept Islam
Pay Jizyah and surrender to Islamic rule
Fight

Conveying this 'dawah' is obligatory (according to the majority view) however it is obligatory to do so only once. If it has already been conveyed in the past then it is not necessity to renew the offer before every attack, rather the Muslims are permitted to carry out a surprise attack when they wish.
If the enemy voluntarily accepts the offer before the battle then it is obligatory on the Muslims to accept it and to refrain from fighting.
The option of Jizyah is not available to everyone. Rather for example it is not available to apostates or to Arab polytheists. While it is available to Jews, Christians and Magians and there is disagreement on the rest of the religions.
This Hadith and Jizyah
The hadith in question and the other texts above do not negate Jizyah if that option is permissible for that specific enemy and has not already been conveyed to the enemy and rejected beforehand.
Jizyah is implicitly mentioned in the hadith as the Prophet's ﷺ instructions to  Abdur Rahman ibn Awf included:

ولا تغدروا
Do not be treacherous (i.e. do not break a treaty)

The contract of Jizyah is a type of a treaty. This treaty involves the disbelievers paying an annual tribute and being subjugated to Islamic laws while being allowed to live and retain their religion in private matters. The hadith instructs the Muslim to not violate treaties, which implies that treaties are permissible to make in the first place.
Further, asking for Jizya is part of fighting process and it is understood that those who agree to pay Jizyah are not fought after that for as long as they abide by their treaty. Similarly it does not negate temporary pauses in fighting due to a treaty or safe conduct. These exceptions are implicit and known from other texts.
Killing
As for killing then the above texts also establish that it is by default permissible to kill all disbelievers. This means regardless of whether they are e.g. idolater or atheist, elite or commoner, soldier or civilian  etc. However this is the default or general rule and there are exceptions, some of which are mentioned or implied in the hadith itself (children and those who have a treaty) and others which are implicit and known from other texts (such as women).

References:

فأما الذين يحاربون فاتفقوا على أنهم جميع المشركين؛
The jurists agreed, with respect to the people who are to be fought, that they are all of the polytheists (muskrikun)
— Bidaayat al-Mujtahid 


وأباح دم الكافر وماله إلا بأن يؤدي الجزية أو يستأمن إلى مدة
And Allah has made the blood and property of a disbeliever lawful except when he pays Jizya or is given asylum for a limited period of time
— Kitab al-Umm 


والأصل فيه أن كل من كان من أهل القتال يحل قتله، سواء قاتل أو لم يقاتل، وكل من لم يكن من أهل القتال لا يحل قتله إلا إذا قاتل حقيقة أو معنى بالرأي والطاعة والتحريض، وأشباه ذلك على ما ذكرنا
The rule is that it is permissible to kill every one who is capable of fighting, regardless of whether they practically fight or do not fight. And it is haram to kill anyone who is not capable of fighting except where they fight in reality or implicitly by giving advice or being obeyed or by inciting others to fight or in any other way which has been mentioned
— Badaa'i' as-Sanaa'i


Footnotes:
1:
The verse 9:123 commands fighting the disbelievers closest to the Muslims in vicinity and then it will apply again to those who are next in vicinity until the whole world and its inhabitants come under Islamic rule. Hence it implies fighting all the disbelievers eventually. See Tafsir al-Qurtubi and  Tafsir al-Mizan  etc. 

I would like to add a significant side note to the answer of UmH.
Quran at-Tawba is revealed during a cease fire period in the fight against the polytheists in and around Mekka, giving rules for the war that would be continuing when the appointed period has expired.
It says in 9:5-6

When the Sacred Months have passed, kill the polytheists wherever you find them. And capture them, and besiege them, and lie in wait for them at every ambush. But if they repent, and perform the prayers, and pay the alms, then let them go their way. God is Most Forgiving, Most Merciful. And if anyone of the polytheists asks you for protection, give him protection so that he may hear the Word of God; then escort him to his place of safety. That is because they are a people who do not know.

9:36

... And fight the polytheists collectively, as they fight you collectively, and know that God is with the righteous.

9:124

O you who believe! Fight those of the disbelievers who attack you, and let them find severity in you, and know that God is with the righteous.

The goal of the fight was conversation. 9:124 implies that the disbelievers who did not attack should somehow be left in peace, but in the end, there was no treaty established that would have granted them sufficient protection, so that there were no confessing polytheists left in Mekka under control of Islam.
There were also Christians and Jews living in the territory. For them, he received
9:25

Fight those who do not believe in God and in the Last Day, forbid what God and His Messenger have forbidden and do not abide by the religion of truth—from among those who received the Scripture—until they pay jizya, willingly or unwillingly.

This means, a treaty should be offered that granted for protection without conversion under the condition of the jizya payment. They should only be fought against if they refuse the agreement.
These are the rules for the war and the following peace treaty, as in the Quran.
The successors waged war over other regions and applied those rules. They encouraged the interpretation of the Surah as a justification to wage war against any non-muslim country. The transmission of hadith has to be seen under this aspect. In particular the omission of the restrictions that are formulated in the Quran should be disputed.
Finally, all Muslim rulers and scholars agreed that Muslim states are allowed to have peace with non-muslim states, and that a Muslim has to respect the integrity of non muslim who don't fight against Islam.
